# Iphone 5 keeps shutting down when I have 40% battery left. Question about reset and restore

Tags: iphone, ios, battery

I have an iPhone 5 (old I know, but I'm rather fond of the compact screen. It's a secondary phone) that was working perfectly until I updated ios. Since the last update available was installed, it keeps shutting down with the battery left.  At first, it was 16% but recently it is 40%.
The battery was changed with an original one 18 months ago.

I tried calibrating the battery but it's impossible to get it to 1% remaining.  At best, I can keep my phone running until it gets to 16% but no lower.

If I reset everything to see if it's a software thing, will I be able to install all the apps again? My worry is that many apps now require recent versions of ios and I'm unsure the app store will let me install old versions again.

Comment: When the phone shuts down and you press the power button immediately after does it show an Apple logo and boot/try to boot or does it show an empty battery sign? If the later is the case the issue is most likely with the battery. An Apple Store or Service Provider could run remote diagnostics to check the battery as well.

Comment: If you still have a Mac with a version of iTunes on it you could possibly perform a backup where the apps are copied as well. This however was discontinued later (especially now that iTunes is gone entirely). Some third party apps (like imazing (not tested, just the first on google)) advertise that they can back up and restore Apps (.ipa files)

Comment: Where did you get the replacement battery from? Apple, or someone else? Sudden shutdowns and wildly unreliable charge readings are usually a sign of a failing battery. I had very similar on my iPhone SE recently, and I got Apple to change the battery, and now it works fine.

Comment: When it shuts down and I try to power on it shows the red battery icon. If I press power+home I get the apple logo and it turns on.  The battery was replaced by Apple by the person who gifted the phone to me. I'm not sure replacing it again is worth it for an old phone with old ios :(  I noticed the issues started with the updates, in particular the 10.3.3 one.